# Is it possible to profile for file system interaction in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, profiling, io

Is it possible to profile a Ruby application to see how much it interacts with the file system?

**Background:** In the past I've written code that reads files within a loop when it only needs to do so once. I'd like to make sure that I eliminate all such code.

Comment: Well, you know, if it's spending too much percent of wall-time in unnecessary I/O, you'll see it pretty quick with a few random halts. Of course, if you're looking for I/O that *doesn't* take much time, it won't help you there.

Comment: @Mike: I'm in the latter situation.

Comment: Something more like a trace, perhaps, on file opens? Sorry, not much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already perfectly capable programs for this purpose out there, that you don't need to duplicate. I don't think you should complicate your program with special logic checking for a relatively obscure programming error (at least, I've never accidentally committed the error you describe). In such cases, the solution is to check a performance characteristic from *outside* the program. Assuming you are on Linux, I would turn to a test/spec that exercises your code and watches [iostat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iostat) (or similar) in a seperate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can simply `require 'profile` at the top of a script:

```
# myscript.rb
require 'profile'
Dir.entries(".").each  { |e| puts e}

$ ruby myscript.rb
```

(list of filenames...)

```
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
  0.00     0.00      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Dir#open
  0.00     0.00      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Dir#each
  0.00     0.00      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Enumerable.to_a
  0.00     0.00      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Dir#entries
  0.00     0.00      0.00       56     0.00     0.00  IO#write
  0.00     0.00      0.00       28     0.00     0.00  IO#puts
  0.00     0.00      0.00       28     0.00     0.00  Kernel.puts
  0.00     0.00      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Array#each
  0.00     0.01      0.00        1     0.00    10.00  #toplevel
```

Or you can just pass in an option on the command line:

```
$ ruby -r profile myscript.rb
```

If you want finer control over what to profile, take a look at the [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/) library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a sucker for brute force.

```
File.open(path, 'r') do |file|
  ...
end
File.mv(path, path + '.hidden')    # Temporary
```

If the code tries to open the file twice, it won't find it the second time.  After the test, you can reverse the rename with a shell one-liner.  In Bash (and probably in other *nix shells as well):

```
for i in `ls *.hidden` ; do mv $i ${i%.hidden} ; done
```